# Converting Large JSON to HTML with Mustache or Handlebars and Reversing the Process from HTML to JSON

Tags: javascript, html, json, vue.js, handlebars.js

I have a collection of JSON files, each containing data ranging from 400 to 500 lines of code (LOC). I need to convert this JSON data into HTML format, complete with appropriate classes, styling, and image rendering in a structured format. Additionally, I also require the capability to reverse this process, converting HTML back to JSON.

I've attempted to use libraries such as Mustache and Handlebars for this task, but I'm encountering issues with the conversion. The resulting HTML doesn't match my expectations, and I'm unsure about how to incorporate styling and images.

Could anyone provide guidance or code examples to help me achieve this conversion and reversal of the process effectively? Any assistance or recommendations would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you in advance!

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>JSON to Mustache</title>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="content"></div>

    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/handlebars.js/4.7.7/handlebars.min.js"></script>

    <script id="image-template" type="text/x-handlebars-template">
      <div class="{{staticClass}}">
          <img src="{{props.src.xs}}" alt="{{name}}" class="{{props['content-class']}}" style="height: {{props.height}};">
      </div>
      <div class="{{scopedSlots.default[0].staticClass}}">
          <div class="{{scopedSlots.default[0].scopedSlots.default[0].staticClass}}">
              <h1>{{scopedSlots.default[0].scopedSlots.default[0].scopedSlots.default[0].props.text}}</h1>
              <p>{{scopedSlots.default[0].scopedSlots.default[0].scopedSlots.default[1].props.text}}</p>
          </div>
      </div>
    </script>

    <script id="container-template" type="text/x-handlebars-template">
      <div class="{{staticClass}}">
          <div class="{{scopedSlots.default[0].staticClass}}">
              <div class="{{scopedSlots.default[0].scopedSlots.default[0].staticClass}}">
                  <h1>{{scopedSlots.default[0].scopedSlots.default[0].scopedSlots.default[0].props.text}}</h1>
                  <p>{{scopedSlots.default[0].scopedSlots.default[0].scopedSlots.default[1].props.text}}</p>
              </div>
          </div>
          <div class="{{scopedSlots.default[1].staticClass}}">
              <div class="{{scopedSlots.default[1].scopedSlots.default[0].staticClass}}">
                  {{scopedSlots.default[1].scopedSlots.default[0].props.code}}
              </div>
          </div>
      </div>
    </script>

    <script>
      $(document).ready(function () {
        const imageData = {
          data: {
            name: "image",
            staticClass: "cms-image",
            props: {
              src: {
                xs: "https://res.cloudinary.com/dfysg77xz/image/upload/v1694437251/qualified_hardware/template/hylu63mzrp0milyyton9.png",
                lg: "https://res.cloudinary.com/dfysg77xz/image/upload/v1694692718/qualified_hardware/template/oyt9f6bs1gulmqphchbe.png",
              },
              "content-class": "d-flex justify-center align-center",
              height: "300px",
            },
            scopedSlots: {
              default: [
                {
                  name: "container",
                  data: {
                    staticClass: "cms-container",
                    scopedSlots: {
                      default: [
                        {
                          name: "row",
                          data: {
                            staticClass: "cms-row",
                            scopedSlots: {
                              default: [
                                {
                                  name: "column",
                                  data: {
                                    staticClass:
                                      "text-center white--text py-12 cms-column",
                                    scopedSlots: {
                                      default: [
                                        {
                                          name: "text",
                                          data: {
                                            staticClass: "mb-6 cms-text",
                                            props: {
                                              text: "Privacy Policy",
                                              as: "h1",
                                            },
                                          },
                                        },
                                        {
                                          name: "text",
                                          data: {
                                            staticClass: "cms-text",
                                            props: {
                                              text: "",
                                              as: "p",
                                            },
                                          },
                                        },
                                      ],
                                    },
                                  },
                                },
                              ],
                            },
                          },
                        },
                      ],
                    },
                  },
                },
              ],
            },
          },
        };

        const containerData = {
          data: {
            name: "container",
            staticClass: "my-12 cms-container",
            scopedSlots: {
              default: [
                {
                  name: "row",
                  data: {
                    staticClass: "cms-row",
                    scopedSlots: {
                      default: [
                        {
                          name: "column",
                          data: {
                            staticClass: "cms-column",
                            props: {
                              cols: {
                                xs: 12,
                                md: 9,
                              },
                            },
                            scopedSlots: {
                              default: [
                                {
                                  name: "html",
                                  data: {
                                    staticClass: "cms-html",
                                    props: {
                                      content:
                                        "<h1>Privacy Policy</h1><p>Last Updated July 21, 2020</p>...",
                                    },
                                  },
                                },
                              ],
                            },
                          },
                        },
                        {
                          name: "column",
                          data: {
                            staticClass: "cms-column",
                            props: {
                              cols: {
                                xs: 12,
                                md: 3,
                              },
                            },
                            scopedSlots: {
                              default: [
                                {
                                  name: "block",
                                  data: {
                                    staticClass: "cms-block",
                                    props: {
                                      code: "template.page.left_block",
                                    },
                                  },
                                },
                              ],
                            },
                          },
                        },
                      ],
                    },
                  },
                },
              ],
            },
          },
        };

        function preprocessData(data) {
          const staticClass = data.data.staticClass; // Extract the staticClass from the data

          // Check if nested structures exist
          if (data.data.scopedSlots && data.data.scopedSlots.default) {
            const defaultData = data.data.scopedSlots.default[0];
            if (defaultData.scopedSlots && defaultData.scopedSlots.default) {
              const textValue = defaultData.scopedSlots.default[0].props.text;

              // Create a new object with flattened data structure
              return {
                name: data.name,
                staticClass: staticClass,
                props: data.data.props,
                text: textValue,
              };
            }
          }

          // If any part of the nested structure is missing, handle it gracefully
          return {
            name: data.name,
            staticClass: staticClass,
            props: data.data.props,
            text: null, // or any default value you prefer
          };
        }

        // Preprocess the JSON data
        const preprocessedImageData = preprocessData(imageData);
        const preprocessedContainerData = preprocessData(containerData);

        // Compile the Handlebars templates (similar to the previous example)
        const imageTemplate = Handlebars.compile(
          document.getElementById("image-template").innerHTML
        );
        const containerTemplate = Handlebars.compile(
          document.getElementById("container-template").innerHTML
        );

        // Render the templates with preprocessed data
        const imageHtml = imageTemplate(preprocessedImageData);
        const containerHtml = containerTemplate(preprocessedContainerData);

        // Insert the rendered HTML into the document
        document.getElementById("content").innerHTML =
          imageHtml + containerHtml;
      });
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: JSON and HTML have no natural 1:1 mapping. Could you share an example of the JSON you're working with, and an example of how you'd ideally like to map that to HTML?

Comment: Don't you a `.data` after each of your `scopedSlots.default[0]` ?